# custom css and js files not load in laravel. How can I fix this?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

css file path is---http://example.com/css/1/styles.css.
I have checked. File is already in the directory.
But not loaded.

Before it was working fine. Suddenly ALL CSS and JS file got 404 error
[css file path via ftp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slEbW.jpg)

[404 for css file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ww9K6.jpg)

Comment: can you please share the directory structure

Comment: @dev dev : Your `styles.css` file stored in `public/css/1/` path right?

Comment: no, root/csss/1/style.css

Comment: Need more info than this for anyone to be able to help

Comment: yes please tell me which info need to know?

Comment: hi make a screenshot about your css folder in the project

Comment: @haffisasma screenshot added.

Comment: try to add to your url {{URL::to('css/1/style.css')}}

Comment: You cannot simply access your root folders like that, you need to put your css, javascript, images, etc in your public folder.